Inner Class unable to access another Inner Class within same Outer Class
I want to access the Inner Class "Item" within the Inner Class "Burger" and add selectedToppings to the list toppings.  I am getting an error on the following line of code - toppings.add(new Item(selectedTopping.toLowerCase(), "topping", 1.00)); - saying "Cannot access dev.lpa.burger.Meal.Item".  I'm unsure as to why this error is coming up.
public Item(String name, String type) {
            this(name, type, type.equals("burger") ? Meal.this.price : 0);
        }

        public Item(String name, String type, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "%10s%15s $%.2f".formatted(type, name,
                    getPrice(price, conversionRate));
        }

        private static double getPrice(double price, double rate) {
            return price * rate;
        }
    }

    private class Burger extends Item {

        enum ToppingTypes {AVOCADO, CHEESE, MAYO, KETCHUP, MUSTARD}

        private List<Item> toppings = new ArrayList<>();

        Burger(String name) {
            super(name, "burger", 5.00);
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return super.price;
        }

        private void addToppings(String[] selectedToppings) {

            for(String selectedTopping : selectedToppings) {
                toppings.add(new Item(selectedTopping.toLowerCase(), "topping", 1.00));
            }
        }
    }

I tried toppings.add(new Item(selectedTopping.toLowerCase(), "topping", 1.00)); and was expecting to be able to add objects of Item to a List of Items.
